# Does the Portal Companion Collection for Switch support keyboard/mouse controls?

Tags: nintendo-switch, gaming-accessories, portal-companion-collection

Does the [Portal Companion Collection for Nintendo Switch](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/portal-companion-collection-switch/) support keyboard/mouse input?

If so, is there anything I need to know about setting it up?

At the time of this writing Nintendo does not provide in the listings on their site any mention whether a title includes KB/M support. This is knowable because other titles that are known to support KB/M such as the [Quake](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/quake-switch/) remaster also include no mention of this. While in the case of Quake I was able to get information about this through Google Search before buying, I have so far had no such luck finding information about KB/M support for the Portal Companion Collection.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried using Kb/mouse with Portal and Portal 2 on Nintendo Switch and as of September 2022, they don't work.